# How to select an option from a dropdown menu in Tableau report webpage using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, webautomation

Python is throwing error when I try to find element by ID or Class name. Please help to find which code will help to pick the data of the specific dropdown

HTML:

```
</div>
<div class="clslblLevelStatus">Level Status</div>
<div class="clsdrpstatus">
    <select id="levelstatusDropdownlist" class="chzn-select-deselect chzn-done" style="width: 200px; display: none;" tabindex="-1">
        <option value=""></option>
    <option value="">--All Statuses--</option><option value="0|1000">Unassigned</option><option value="1|15">L1 - Work In Progress</option><option value="1|14">L1 - Pending</option><option value="1|2">L1 - Hold</option><option value="1|1">L1 - Completed</option><option value="1|3">L1 - Invalid</option><option value="2|15">L2 - Work In Progress</option><option value="2|14">L2 - Pending</option><option value="2|2">L2 - Hold</option><option value="2|3">L2 - Invalid</option><option value="3|15">L3 - Work In Progress</option><option value="3|14">L3 - Pending</option><option value="3|2">L3 - Hold</option><option value="3|3">L3 - Invalid</option><option value="0|1001">Completed</option></select><div id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 200px;" title=""><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single chzn-default" tabindex="-1"><span>Select an Option</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 198.4px; top: 23px;"><div class="chzn-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" style="width: 163.8px;"></div><ul class="chzn-results"><li id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn_o_1" class="active-result" style="">--All Statuses--</li><li id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn_o_2" class="active-result" style="">Unassigned</li><li id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn_o_3" class="active-result" style="">L1 - Work In Progress</li><li id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn_o_4" class="active-result" style="">L1 - Pending</li><li id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn_o_5" class="active-result" style="">L1 - Hold</li><li id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn_o_6" class="active-result" style="">L1 - Completed</li><li id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn_o_7" class="active-result" style="">L1 - Invalid</li><li id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn_o_8" class="active-result" style="">L2 - Work In Progress</li><li id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn_o_9" class="active-result" style="">L2 - Pending</li><li id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn_o_10" class="active-result" style="">L2 - Hold</li><li id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn_o_11" class="active-result" style="">L2 - Invalid</li><li id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn_o_12" class="active-result" style="">L3 - Work In Progress</li><li id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn_o_13" class="active-result" style="">L3 - Pending</li><li id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn_o_14" class="active-result" style="">L3 - Hold</li><li id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn_o_15" class="active-result" style="">L3 - Invalid</li><li id="levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn_o_16" class="active-result" style="">Completed</li></ul></div></div>
```

I have tried the below code

```
Queue_status = Select(browser.find_element(By.ID,'levelstatusDropdownlist'))
Queue_status.select_by_visible_text("--All Statuses--")

Queue_status = browser.find_element(By.ID,'levelstatusDropdownlist_chzn'))
Queue_status.click()
```

Comment: hi, could you please share the url you are testing. Also add error message that you get in your question. thx

Answer (score 0):

The `<select>` is having the property *`style="width: 200px; display: none;"`* so you can't use the `<select>` tag.

---

### Solution

To select an option you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code block:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a//span[text()='Select an Option']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='chzn-drop']//ul[@class='chzn-results']//li[text()='L2 - Work In Progress']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```